# header Location redirect with anchor tag and IE7

Tags: php, html, anchor

Hey there! Here is my issue, it could just be a browser issue but any help/ideas would be awesome!

Pretty much I have the following redirect:

```
header("Location: page.php#images");
```

In most modern browsers it will redirect to page.php#images without any problems but in IE it seems to strip the #images.  Has anyone come across this?  So far my only option (which I think is a terrible option) is to redirect through JavaScript.

thanks!

*UPDATE*
I sent up a simple sandbox and it seems to work fine with or without an absolute URL.  I guess there is something else going on in my actual app that is conflicting with it.  I'll update when I figure it out, thanks for all the responses!

*UPDATE 2*
I found out what the problem is but I am still unsure on the fix.  It turns out that it was a file input that was breaking it.  You can see it in action here http://www.stiprojects.com/anchor/  it works fine in firefox but breaks in IE.  the source code in the redirect is:

```
header("Location: http://www.stiprojects.com/anchor/index.php?one=1&two=2#/images");
```

Do you see anything that I'm not seeing? I'm so confused!

Comment: I just tested this and it's working fine for me on IE7.

Comment: the link works but the form doesn't (in IE 7)

Answer (score 2):

The `Location` header requires an absolute path per the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30). Try using an absolute path. The [errata](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/rfc2616bis/issues/) says that document fragments (#id) are allowed in the Location header, but the behaviour when a user is linked to a page with a fragment (e.g. `http://example.org/a_redirector#this` where `a_redirector` redirects to `http://example.com/destination#that`) is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is true.  It can be prevented if you use an absolute path:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/page.php#images");
```