# can i redirect to an internal link using php?

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am trying to set a redirect to an internal link with php. Basicaly, i am doing an app using jquerymobile, and the navigation requires that you navigate through divs rather than documents. However, the code i figured out looks like this

```
if (isset($_POST['insert'])) {
    $post = $_POST['wish'];
    $fk_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $succes = "";
    $succes .= "<h1>SUCCES</h1>";
    $insert_wish_sql = "INSERT INTO wishlist(wish_id, wish, fk_id, datetime) VALUES ('', '$post', '$fk_id' , CURDATE())";//insert new post
    $res = mysql_query($insert_wish_sql);

    if ($insert_wish_sql) {
        header('Location:#wishlist');
    }
}
```

I also tryied Location:index.php#wishlist
any ideas?

Comment: If there is no <a> tag with that attribute you will need to process the page position with javascript.

Comment: How about using AJAX with jquery ? You could update your database, then you could update the item to the list youre viewing and move yourself to the item.

Comment: If i only had any experience with AJAX that would be great..

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  The `Location:` header is for the HTTP client, and HTTP doesn't really care about the anchor fragment.  Plus, the RFCs require that URLs specified in that header be full URLs.

Now, what you can get away with sometimes is linking to the actual resource with the anchor fragment.

```
header('Location: http://example.com/someResource#wishlist');
```

Also, you should know that your code is wide open to SQL injection attacks, and you will be hacked if you haven't been already.  [Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html) or similar to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is loading an anchor in HTML.
You should try redirecting to an absolute path, like this:

```
header('Location: http://host.name/index.php#wishlist');
```

You might also want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963211/header-location-redirect-with-anchor-tag-and-ie7%20this%20answer).